# Pass string from one subclass to another

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am calling a web service to get a object out of the json, then I need to pass that object that I have made a string to another web service. I have each web service call in a AsyncTask. I am unable to pass that first jsonObject named map to another subClass. Don't worry about the actaul calls, I want to pass the string "map" to the second AsyncTask to be able to use that in the web call. Both these classes are sub classes.

```
 public class aisleStoreID extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String urlExtension = "getpartnerstore?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng + "&partner_id=" + "60" + "&vendor_store_nbr=" + id + "";
        final String authToken = Utils.md5(urlExtension);

        String urlString = "http://aisle411.ws/webservices2/getpartnerstore.php?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng + "&partner_id=" + 60 + "&vendor_store_nbr=" + id + "&auth=" + authToken;


        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            HttpResponse response = ConnectionHelper.executeHttpGetStoreMap(urlString);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            if (response != null) {
                result = response.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(sb));
                JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stores");
                JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                String map = jObj.getString("store_map_url");


                Intent intent = new Intent(this, getStoreMap.class);
                intent.putExtra("retailer_store_id", map);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        System.out.println("  What's in it" + result);
    }
}

public class getStoreMap extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String storeMap = bundle.getString("retailer_store_id");

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlExtension = "map?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng + "&partner_id=" + "60" + "&retailer_store_id=" + map + "";
        final String authToken = Utils.md5(urlExtension);
        String urlString = "http://aisle411.ws/webservices2/map.php?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng + "&partner_id=" + 60 + "&retailer_store_id=" + map + "&auth=" + authToken;*/

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks fair.  what is exact problem? storeMap is null?

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place? Why can't the first `AsyncTask` do all the work in it `doInBackground`? You're tightly coupling the two `AsyncTasks` anyways, so they're not really reusable in other places...

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code of extracting `storeMap` from `extras` to `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in your aisleStoreID AsyncTask' onPostExecute():

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        System.out.println("  What's in it" + result);
        String params[]=new String[1];
        params[0]=result;
        new getStoreMap().execute(params);
    }
```

and then get the params in doInBackground of getStoreMap AsyncTask.

Note: Intent is used to send extras from one to another component(like activity,services,Broadcast Receivers or Content Providers) , not between classes or subclasses.

Comment: Still confused on how this is passing the map value from the JSONArray to be able to use in another web service call. The sdk I am using requires me to get a value from 1 call, then pass that value into another call to be able to get a image. I am really confused on how to pass this map value to another web service call. Am I able to call 2 web service calls within the same AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

An Async Task isn't meant to be an activity. It's meant to work in the background while you get the data for the activity.  The difference is important and I would recommend reading up on it in the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I would try returning map from doInBackground and then calling the other AsyncTask in the onPostExecute also you might be able to collapse some of those variables from

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(sb));
JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stores");
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
```

to this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(sb)).getJSONArray("stores").getJSONObject(0);
```

#### In onPostExecute

```
public class aisleStoreID extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // ...
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        new getStoreMap().execute(result);
    }
}
```